# pandas: get the highest values in an entire dataframe, and row/col values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, of sales by department by year:

```
 department    2001    2002    2003    ...
 Food          1300    1444    1573    ...
 Music         1370    1244    1173    ...
```

I want to find the 10 highest values across the whole dataset, and see the department and year for each one.

Is there any way I can find both at the same time? I know how to get the highest value in each row (`idxmax`) and each column (`idxmax(axis=1)`), but I don't know how to search the entire dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this (simple case of 3-largest here):

```
>>> df.stack().sort_values(ascending=False).nlargest(3)

sports  2002    72
music   2001    67
sports  2001    54
dtype: int64
```

To create this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(444)
depts = ['food', 'music', 'sports']
years = list(range(2001, 2004))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, (3, 3)),
                  columns=years, index=depts)
print(df)
#         2001  2002  2003
# food       3    23     8
# music     67    52    12
# sports    54    72    41
```

You can also throw in `.swaplevel()` to the resulting Series if wanted:

```
>>> df.stack().swaplevel().sort_values(ascending=False).nlargest(3)

2002  sports    72
2001  music     67
      sports    54
```